# change value that doesn't equal certain strings

Tags: r

I have a variable containing values like Android, Linux, Windows, iOS, etc..

I want to keep the values that equal Android, Windows and iOS, but the other values should be changed to "Other".

I thought this was easy, I tried to do this with gsub(), but I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl`

```
v1[!grepl("\\b(Android|Linux|Windows|iOS)\\b", v1) & !is.na(v1)] <- "Others"
```

Or if it is not partial matches, we can also use `%in%`

```
v2[!v2 %in% c("Android", "Linux", "Windows", "iOS") & !is.na(v2)] <- "Others"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Android phone", "Linux OS", "Windows OS", "A", "iOS", "B", NA)
v2 <- c("Android", "Linux", "Windows", "A", "iOS", "B", NA)
```

Comment: I just noticed that values with NA also change to Others, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @M.D.  Updated the post.  Just use a condition to exclude NA with `is.na`

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all(v2[!is.na(v2)], "^(?!Android|Windows|iOS).*$","Others ")` But I think you mean NULL or ''?